# In Graph API how can I get who mentioned me

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Graph API to fetch my page feeds. I call

```
$pageID/feed?fields=created_time,object_id,story_tags,story,full_picture,picture,message_tags,message,caption,child_attachments,attachments,description,admin_creator,from
```

It gives me the feeds in my page which is fine. But, I also want the list of posts where anyone has mentioned my page in their posts in their own walls. I have gone through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9 but could not find a way to do that. Does anyone has any idea if that is possible?
If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

There is the `/{page-id}/tagged` endpoint; but that will only return posts by other pages that have tagged yours, and only if those pages are “authentic” (which likely means verified.)

And user posts are not available at all to your app, not even if they are public - unless the user explicitly granted your app permission to read their posts.